# Titan graph: Edge property with Cardinality.LIST? Where is StandardEdge.addProperty()?

Tags: java, graph-databases, titan

We use Titan 0.5.4.
We use Frames framework for OGM, which we customized to support inheritance.
We have a [Titan index](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/indexes.html#graph-indexes) set on property which holds "type discriminators" (see Hibernate):

```
PropertyKey propKey = getOrCreatePropertyKey(titan, "w:type", String.class), Cardinality.LIST);
titan.buildIndex("edge-type", Edge.class).addKey("w:type").buildCompositeIndex();
```

Now, the existence of `buildIndex`'s 2nd param suggests that edges should also be able to accomodate `Cardinality.LIST` properties.
However, when you want to add these properties, there's no method for it:

```
if (abstractElement instanceof StandardEdge)
    ((StandardEdge) abstractElement).addProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
```

Except there is NO `addProperty()`, only `setProperty()` which overwrites the value, and Javadoc specifically states:

> Sets the value for the given key on this element. The key must be defined to have Cardinality.SINGLE, otherwise this method throws an exception

So I wonder,

How can I put multiple values to edge's property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Titan 0.5.4. Unfortunately it is not allowed to use multi-property (cardinality different from `Cardinality.SINGLE`) for edge properties in Titan. It is not clear described in Titan 0.5.4 documentation [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/advanced-schema.html#_multi_properties).

> Titan supports multiple properties with the same key on a single **vertex**

Same story in Titan 1.0.0 only difference that method `addPropery` changed to `property`. Documentation is [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/advanced-schema.html#_multi_properties).